# How do people navigate contract software article editor/writer work?

Tags: payments, pay-rate, software, writing

I recently had a company reach out asking if I'd be interested in editing and writing programming articles for them (basically dev advocate related). I have 10 years experience as a software engineer. In the past I've written a bunch of technical articles, but it's always been as part of my job or for my personal site.

What is considered "average pay" when writing vs. editing 500-3000 word technical articles? How do you charge for this kind of work?